# How can I fix this circular dependency?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I have three headers that are structured like this:

### baz.h

```
#pragma once
#include "foo.h"

class Foo;
class Bar;

class Baz
{
};
```

### bar.h

```
#pragma once
#include "foo.h"

class Foo;
class Baz;

class Bar : public Foo
{
};
```

### foo.h

```
#pragma once
#include "baz.h"
#include "bar.h"

class Baz;
class Bar;

class Foo
{
};
```

Including these headers is currently giving me errors in `bar.h`, saying that the base class `Foo` is undefined.

I thought I had wrapped my head around circular dependencies, and had added forward declarations accordingly, so why won't this code compile?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's *obvious* how they're circular. One includes the other which includes the one. It's only 2 levels deep.

Comment: You include `foo.h` in `bar.h`, but `foo.h` includes `bar.h`. Remove the include of `bar.h` from `foo.h`

Comment: Remove `#include "baz.h"` and `#include "bar.h"` from foo.h

Comment: A base class can't be forward declared

Comment: @NicolBolas You're completely right. I've edited the title accordingly

Comment: Only include the headers the code directly depends on.  ( [*include what you use*](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use) )  Superfluous includes can cause an unnecessary circular dependency.  Use forward declarations or header-header files that have the forward declarations as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

That is obvious, `baz.h` and `bar.h` need `foo.h` and `foo.h` it self needs `bar.h` and `baz.h`. Create a `types.h` and forward declare those types and include them into header file and include actual types header into the source codes.

Or simply put all the classes into a single header file.

Comment: The code is not complete enough to say if foo.h needs to include baz.h or bar.h

Comment: @drescherjm `foo.h` needs them both. That's why I'm including them. The code in the question didn't include the usage of `Baz` and `Bar` in `Foo` because that was not the focus of the question.

Comment: You need to remove that dependency to break the circular header dependency. The forward declarations do not help if you are going to include on top of the forward declaration.

Comment: @drescherjm Are you sure that that's the case? The solution that Ghasem Ramezani suggested doesn't seem to involve that.